# Is it possible to declare data-attributes as constants

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, custom-data-attribute

I have a tag defined

```
<tr data-hideable-category="hideablerow_@(availableGame.DivisionId)">...</tr>
```

As of the `data-hideable-category` attribute is used in markup and later on in `JavaScript` I wondered if it would be possible to define `data-hideable-category` as a constant string in order to avoid magic strings.

Something like

```
<tr @Constants.HideableCategory="hideablerow_@(availableGame.DivisionId)">...</tr>
```

I would use it like

```
$("[@Constants.HideableCategory]").on('click', ...)
```

Comment: Why? you can't put your code in an external javascript file if you do this

Comment: @charlietfl: Good point, but currently there is no `external` javascript-file. So I guess there is no easy way to achieve avoiding `magic strings` and have js and cshtml splitted?

Comment: Not understanding what your problem is to be honest

Comment: My problem is to have names I need to depend on in JS and CSHTML defined twice. If I change the name on one side the code will not work anymore.

Comment: Pass a config object to a js variable. Then you aren't bound to having razor code mixed in with javascript

Answer (score 0):

If i understand truly...

> html:

```
<tr data-category='@Constants.HideableCategory="hideablerow_@(availableGame.DivisionId)'</tr>
```

> js:

```
$("[data-category='somting value']").on('click', ...){};
```

you can see http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp for other selectors